# Jenkins / How to build 1 repo each time one of my 100 repos is updated

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a git repository which I want to build every time that one of my 100 other repositories is updated.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Jenkins job configuration page.

Activate *trigger builds remotely* in the *build triggers* section and put a random token in the *authentication token field*.

It gives you a URL. Every time you request it with your token, Jenkins will run a build. So the aim is to make the Git server request this URL after each push.

To do that you must use *git hooks*. These allow you to define some things to do when an event such as push is triggered.

On the Git server file system under `/my-project.git/hooks`, create a `post-receive` file with in it the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl my-jenkins-url/buildWithParameters?token=my-token
```

Do that for all your 100 repositories and every time one is updated, the Jenkins job will run.